# How to add google adsense code in prestashop 1.7 footer?

Tags: prestashop, footer, adsense

How can we add google Adsense code in my PrestaShop 1.7 footer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Just go to this file /themes/classic/templates/_partials/footer.tpl
Then enter like this it will work 

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    {block name='hook_footer_before'}
      {hook h='displayFooterBefore'}
    {/block}
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      {block name='hook_footer'}
        {hook h='displayFooter'}
      {/block}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      {block name='hook_footer_after'}
        {hook h='displayFooterAfter'}
      {/block}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="text-sm-center">
          {block name='copyright_link'}
            <a class="_blank" href="#" target="_blank">
              {l s='%copyright% 2010 - %year% - Shop by %prestashop%' sprintf=['%prestashop%' => 'DICE','%year%' => 'Y'|date, '%copyright%' => '©'] d='Shop.Theme.Global'}
            </a>
          {/block}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block; text-align:center;"
     data-ad-layout="in-article"
     data-ad-format="fluid"
     data-ad-client="xxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxx"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>
```

For the reference you can check my website https://diceindiagroup.net